# Go error "undefined: sync.Pool" when installing go-mtpfs

Tags: go, debian

Running the command

```
sudo go get github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs
```

I get the following output:

```
/usr/lib/go/src/pkg/github.com/hanwen/go-fuse/fuse/bufferpool.go:41: undefined: sync.Pool
/usr/lib/go/src/pkg/github.com/hanwen/go-fuse/fuse/bufferpool.go:54: undefined: sync.Pool
/usr/lib/go/src/pkg/github.com/hanwen/go-fuse/fuse/server.go:44: undefined: sync.Pool
/usr/lib/go/src/pkg/github.com/hanwen/go-fuse/fuse/server.go:47: undefined: sync.Pool
```

What does this mean? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error message means that the `go-fuse` library uses `sync.Pool`, which was introduced in Go 1.3 (changes for that release: https://golang.org/doc/go1.3) and I suspect that the Go version you've installed on your system is older (e.g. on Debian stable (wheezy) it's 1.0.2). In order to use the `go-fuse` library you'll need to use a Go version of at least 1.3.